# How to get tcp/ip monitor to use authentication in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, authentication, proxy, tcp, ibm-rad

I have a web-service defined in XML (EJB project). I override this endpoint and send it through the tcp/ip monitor - which works fine, however I get:

> javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: HTTP ( 401 ) Unauthorized address

I know the credentials and can hit the service through a browser but I can't seem to get Eclipse (IBM's RAD version) to allow me to specify the security credentials, there's no option for it:

[image: tcp/ip monitor options]

In my XMLI have:

> overriddenEndpointURI="http://localhost:8887/xxx/xxx/ServiceName"

Any suggestions?